# Why doesn't it work to pass matrix to function if it is statically declared without mentioning the size in the function header?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make the code below work, but as far as I have read, there are two options to pass a matrix to a function:

1. specify the size of the matrix in header like this: `void f(int v[100][100], int n)`
2. dynamically alocate it instead of `int a[100][100]`

Why wouldn't it work like in the code below? Isn't saying int a[100][100] the same as allocating it dynamically? Isn't a[i][j] the same as * ( *(a+i)+j)?

```
void f(int **v, int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) printf("%d ", v[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[100][100],n=5,i,j;
    f(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there is no *matrix* type and `int[100][100]` is not compatible with `int **v`.

Comment: because pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointers, that's why you can write:

```
void foo(int *p);
void foo(int p[]); // equivalent (use the above form)

int v[100];
foo(v);
```

For a multidimension array, only the first order array "decays". So a matrix (think of it as an array of arrays) decays to pointer to array:

```
void foo(int (*p)[100]);
void foo(int p[][100]);   // equivalent (use the above form)

int m[100][100];
foo(m);
```

---

The reason has to do with memory layout:

One dimension array:

```
char v[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

| a | b | c |
```

As you can see it is fairy trivial to access this via a `char *` pointer.

Two dimension array:

```
char m[2][3] = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}};

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
|           |           |
```

The above array could not decay to a `char **`. A `char **` would have this layout:

```
| addr | addr | addr | ...
```

That is in memory there would be pointers to char stored.

So `m` can decay to pointer to array 3 of char `char (*p)[3]`. The `3` has to be known, because that gives the size of the deferenced object, which absolutely needs to be known: for the dereference and pointer arithmetics to work (e.g. `p++`)

```
char (*p)[3]:

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
|           |           |
```

So the first p element, `p[0]` is the `char[3]` array `{a,b,c}` and `p[1]` is the `char[3]` array `{d,e,f}`

---

Note I used `char` to better show elements as characters. But those are not C-strings as they are not NULL terminated. Substitute with `int` if it makes you more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

When a function parameter is declared as having type of an array it is adjusted to pointer to the type of the array element.

Accordingly when an array is passed to a function as an argument or used in an expression it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So if you have an array

```
int a[100][100];
```

and uses its name as an argument to some function

```
some_function( a, 100 );
```

then it is converted to type `int ( * )[100]`.

Correspondingly the function parameter must be declared one of the following ways

```
void f( int a[100][100], size_t n );
```

or

```
void f( int a[][100], size_t n );
```

or

```
void f( int ( *a )[100], size_t n );
```

all these declarations are equivalent and declare the same one function.

You could define the array dynamically as for example

```
int ( *a )[100] = malloc( 100 * 100 * sizeof( int ) );
```

and call the function the same way as it is shown above

```
some_function( a, 100 );
```

However if you will define dynamically a one-dimensional array of arrays as for example

```
int **a = malloc( 100 * sizeof( int *  ) );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) a[i] = malloc( 100 * sizeof( int ) );
```

then as you can see the type of variable `a` is `int **`. It is not the same as `int ( *a )[100]`. So the function should be declared like

```
void f( int *a[100], size_t n );
```

or

```
void f( int *a[], size_t n );
```

or

```
void f( int **a, size_t n );
```

As you see there are shown two different declarations of arrays and pointers and correspondingly two different function declarations that depend on the types of the arrays or pointers.